# what does @ mean in case of `pip install <package> @ path`?

Tags: python, pip

I just came across this from a project on GitHub

```
pip install colorama @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/colorama_1602866480661/work
```

what does @ do ?
assuming it decides the path where to install, I tried using any path and it wouldn't work like that

Also, why would we want to do so?
Also, what is the significance of `file:///`

Here is the link to the project

https://github.com/sstzal/DFRF/blob/main/requirements.txt

Thanks for your attention

Comment: I think it needs to be put between quotes : `python -m pip install 'color @ file:///home/...'` and it specifies the location of a file that should be used to install 'colorama' (the source, not the destination). See: https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#direct-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation with an `@` is specified [here in the "Direct references" section of *PEP 440*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#direct-references).

The part after the `@` is a direct reference to a location where the project can be installed from (i.e. the source, not the destination).

It can be URL to a file archive (*sdist* or *wheel*), or a VCS repository (git, for example).

The `file://` notation is meant for the (local) filesystem protocol (as opposed to the `https://` protocol for example).